# GDS-show data from another sheet beside column grand total

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have created a pivot table in data-studio from a google sheet. Another sheet in the same workbook contains a table that has a column named `total`. I want to show this `total` column beside the "column grand total" of the pivot table created from the first sheet.

Can this be done using data blending? If yes, how can I do it?
[image: pivot]

link to GDS report : https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9e869103-e0f8-43eb-a0d2-0147ef4628cf

Desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: Please, provide access to your sheets.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11BaK4xQ5I-4lG3fDOotMFgbmTkP0y48Gf2CzcIiKb3I/edit?usp=sharing             Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your data, `Class A` and `Class B` are join keys (since they are the data data appear in both data sources); `Class C` and `Totals` are dimensions (you can treat `Totals` as a metric, the result will be the same); and `Record Count` is a metric.

Knowing this, everything you need to do is to blend your data, as follows:

[image: Blending example]

Using this new data source in a pivot table, add `Class A`, `Class B` and `Totals` as row dimensions of your pivot table, `Class C` as column dimension and `Record Count` as metric.  The result should be:

[image: Pivot table result]

Obviously, you can't have everything you want.  In a pivot table, row dimensions appear first, then metrics and totals.  It doesn't make sense to add it as the last column as you want, at least not with standard controls.